# excel - if() and search() to return word next the word to be searched

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

I just join this forum and like everyone else, I am very new to using excel function feature.

So I have this function: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ACURA",A1)),"????"))`

Value of A1 cell = `"ACURA TL 2010-2016 BODY KIT"`

I want to use function above to:

1. Search for keyword ACURA and return the word next to the right of it which is "TL". Is it possible? Can someone please show me how?
2. I want to search for keyword "20" and return the whole word after it which is "2010-2016".

I am trying to build a part filter for our company website which require Make, Model, and Year attributes. All we have is the product names.

Thank you

Comment: You could use text-to-columns to separate the words then you would have every part of the string.

Comment: The Text-To-Columns is what you really want - it's quick, and splits out all the info, and leaves you with a decently sortable table.  However, to get the "TL", you can use `Mid()`. (Assume `D1` is your cell with the string): `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ACURA",D1)),TRIM(MID(D1,SEARCH(" ",D1,1)+1,2)))`

Comment: What @BruceWayne said will work if "Acura" will always be the first word, and the second piece will always have a length of two. Much harder to do this when the length is variable. That could be fixed by finding the space after the word and using that to help determine your lenght.

Comment: @Kyle - Yeah, that's the thing, it's not very easy to do with formula. I know it's possible, yeah, but Brandcreative, I'd go with Text-To-Columns.  You could, of course, replace `"ACURA"` with `Z1` if `Z1` has "ACURA"...but good to note.

Comment: @BruceWayne agreed on the Text-to-Columns. The one downside to that is if you have poorly formatted data, which seems to be pervasive, you might get blank cells. I tend to assume the data will be garbage and that a solution needs to be flexible enough to deal with that. Maybe I'm just a "glass half empty" type...or I've been plagued with poor data consistency....

Comment: @Kyle - Oh for sure, I'm with you - assume the worst.  If OP gave more info, we could dive into that end...but right now, with what we know, I am assuming it's standardized data.  I'm usually just happy if there's any water in the glass, whether it's half empty or half full :P

Comment: Thank you everyone. Text-to-column is one of the solution that we know ofbut sometimes the vendors don't always give us the standard product names but a lot of time they are all mix up.  Thank you all